# channel of type interface not receiving value in golang with MySql

Tags: mysql, go, goroutine

I am new to golang. I am trying to do concurrent queries to mysql db with golang. I know channels can be of the type interface. When I print `tableData (type map)` in `RunQuery` function I am getting the result. I am sending `tableData` to `ch` i.e. channel of type interface. In function `getdataList` I am not getting any value in `ch`. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Following is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "log"
)


var db *sql.DB

func getdataList(id int) {
        ch := make(chan interface{})
        done := make (chan bool)
        RunQuery(ch,"select id,name, last_name,first_name from persons where id= ?", id)
        go func() {
            for {
            x, ok := <-ch //I am not getting any data in channel here
            if ok {
                fmt.Println(x)
            }else {
                fmt.Println("done")
                done <- true
                return
            }

        }
        }()
    }

func RunQuery (ch chan interface{}, query string, param interface{}) {

    stmt, err := db.Prepare(query)
    if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }
    defer stmt.Close()
    rows, err := stmt.Query(param)
    columns, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to get columns", err)
        return
    }
    count := len(columns)
    tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    values := make([]interface{}, count)
    valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)
    for rows.Next() {
      for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
          valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]
      }
      rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)
      entry := make(map[string]interface{})
      for i, col := range columns {
          var v interface{}
          val := values[i]
          b, ok := val.([]byte)
          if ok {
              v = string(b)
          } else {
              v = val
          }
          entry[col] = v
      }
      tableData = append(tableData, entry)
  }
    fmt.Pritln(tableData) //here I am getting data in map
    ch <- tableData
}


func dbtest(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    go getdataList(2)
    go getdataList(3)
}

func main() {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/dbName")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())  
    }
    defer db.Close()

    http.HandleFunc("/dbTest", dbtest)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it is blocking the execution flow before data can be read from the channel. When you call `RunQuery` from `getdataList`, `RunQuery` tries to send data over channel `ch`. However, nothing is reading from `ch` because the code to read from it is in `getdataList` and it's below the call to `RunQuery`.

Therefore, `RunQuery` never returns and the goroutine to read from `ch` never fires. To fix, You can try running `RunQuery` as a goroutine as well:

```
func getdataList(id int) {
        ch := make(chan interface{})
        done := make (chan bool)
        // run in a goroutine
        go RunQuery(ch,"select id,name, last_name,first_name from persons where id= ?", id)
        go func() {
            for {
            x, ok := <-ch //I am not getting any data in channel here
            if ok {
                fmt.Println(x)
            }else {
                fmt.Println("done")
                done <- true
                return
            }

        }
    }()
}
```

There is another issue in your code. You are never closing `ch`. This may result in deadlock. The most ideal place to do this appears to be in `RunQuery`:

```
func RunQuery (ch chan interface{}, query string, param interface{}) {
    // ...
    ch <- tableData
    close(ch)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine. I have a question though, where should i add close(ch) in my code. Also, that done is not getting printed. Will it print only when channel is closed ?

Comment: I am having a doubt, In `fun dbtest` if I don't use `getdataList` with go routines. Using apache benchmark I get better performance if i don't use the two `getdataList` functions with go routine. Can u explain me why?

Comment: I cannot say with certainty but my guess would be that with goroutines, concurrent access is forcing sql's `db` to open two connections. Without goroutines, first call to `getdataList` creates one connection, which is then used by the second call to `getdataList`. My advice would be to update `getdataList` so it takes a list of ids and fetches most of the data with a single query. In that case, `getdataList([]int{2, 3})` with an similarly updated sql query would provide even better performance.

Comment: Hey, would you mind helping me with another problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122458/get-post-data-using-golang-http-package/39122551#39122551