# Get post data using golang http package

Tags: http, go

I am new to golang, getting familiar with http package. I am having trouble in getting the post data I am sending using postman.

`http://localhost:8084/dbTest` is my URI. I am passing key: `hub_id` value: `1` using form-data. I tried following approaches,

```
req.ParseForm()
fmt.Println("hub_id", req.Form["hub_id"])
req.Form.Get("hub_id")
```

But none of the approach work. I am getting empty response.

Following is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
) 

func dbtest(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  req.ParseForm()
  fmt.Println("hub_id", req.Form["hub_id"])
  req.Form.Get("hub_id")
  fmt.Println(req.PostFormValue("hub_id")) //response is empty
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/dbTest", dbtest)

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8084", nil))
}
```

When I print req i get the following:

```
&{POST /dbTest HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Origin:[chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop] Connection:[keep-alive] Content-Type:[multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydFOTVjOJMeqOHnS3] Content-Length:[138] Accept-Language:[en-US,en;q=0.8] Cache-Control:[no-cache] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate] Accept:[*/*] User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36] Postman-Token:[ac7ae3a9-60f6-2146-3f1c-209de7622774]] 0xc210012e70 138 [] false localhost:8084 map[] map[] <nil> map[] 127.0.0.1:34152 /dbTest <nil>}
```

**Solution:** I found the solution. Since, content-type is `mulipart/form-data` I correct way to parse form is to use `req.ParseMultipartForm` http method.

Comment: Please show your html template.

Comment: I am sending data via postman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using incorrect `Content-Type`. When using `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `r.ParseForm()` will parse data correctly. Check `r.Form` afterwards.

Comment: Will you please explain it more. Here the content type is `Content-Type:[multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydFOTVjOJMeqOHnS3]` which is send by POSTMAN.

Comment: Take a look here for explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data#answer-4073451 In Postman, you can define different `Content-Type`. In body section, below URL address you can pick different types.

Comment: yes, I got the value by using `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but suppose in future i will have to send `binary (non-alphanumeric) data (or a significantly sized payload) ` then `multipart/form-data` should be used. How to obtain POST data when content-type is `multipart/form-data` in go.

Comment: I found the solution. Since, content-type is `mulipart/form-data` ,the correct way to parse form is to use `req.ParseMultipartForm` http method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
err := r.ParseForm()
v := r.Form
h := v.Get("hub_id")
```

Edit: I see you've tried ParseForm

Comment: Are you posting the data, i.e. Method="POST" from a form ?

Comment: Try adding a Methods("POST") to the handleFunc ?

Comment: err := r.ParseForm() prints <nil>
v := r.Form prints map[]
h := v.Get("hub_id") prints nothing

Comment: Also, when i print req.Method it prints POST. This means that it is a POST request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121732/discussion-between-jagrati-and-sridhar).